# Suppress IDE0063 only for TransactionScope type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis

Is it possible to suppress: `Use simple 'using' statement (IDE0063)` only for specific type - `TransactionScope` for example.

I have `csharp_prefer_simple_using_statement = true` in my `.editorconfig`.
Is it possible to provide global `SuppressMessageAttribute` that targets all usages of `using (var ts = new TransactionScope())`?

Comment: Possibly, but why? That's just a suggestion, not a warning

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why should there be a specific reason? I just don't want it to be suggested for that type. Maybe i want to fix all suggestions in the solution, but without those ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. Code style language rules can only specify the value and severity. Please see [Language rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/language-rules) and [Configuration options for code analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options).

The best option may to configure its severity level to `suggestion`.